# How do I find $x$ for a parabola such that the arc length is equal to

Tags: calculus

Assuming the start of the arc segment is $x=0$, how can I find the $x$ value such that the arc length of a parabola is equal to a certain length?

Comment: Please, tell us what you tried.

Comment: Do you know the formula for arc length?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't really know where to start. I found the equation for an arc length, but I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: the formula for the arc length between $x=a$ and $x=b$ is: $$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx$$

Comment: Yes I did find this formula, but I don't really know what to do with it... I'm a programmer and while I understand vector math reasonably well, I'm pretty bad at calculus.

Comment: That is awesome, thanks! I don't understand the magic behind this, but that makes it super easy to solve for q. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, If you want, you can thank me by clicking on the arrow above the 0. Thanks!

Comment: I would but I don't have the rep to upvote... :( sorry.

Comment: No problem! ;-)